# how to Store Associative Array data in Database

Tags: php, mysql, asana

here is my code:

```
$user_detail = $client->fetch("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/"
    .$response['result']['data'][$i]['id'].'.json');


echo  $q="INSERT INTO `asana_users`(`Name`, `Email`,`Workspaces`) VALUES  ('".$user_detail['result']['data']['name']."',
    '".$user_detail['result']['data']['email']."','" .implode("'),
    ('"$user_detail['result']['data']['workspaces'][$i])."') "; 

$user_fetch = mysql_query($q);
```

1. Thing i want to insert data of

   ```
              [workspaces] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => Array
                           (
                               [id] => ********
                               [name] => a.com
                           )

                       [1] => Array
                           (
                               [id] => **********
                               [name] => Personal Projects
                           )
   ```

   here is my array fetched now i want to add index 0 contains id , name in workplace field.
2. secondly how to fetch data
3. please suggest

   ```
           Array
            (
         [result] => Array
               (
           [data] => Array
           (
               [id] => ****
               [name] => hiuh
               [email] => a@d.com
               [photo] => 
               [workspaces] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => Array
                           (
                               [id] => 1
                               [name] => a.com
                           )

                       [1] => Array
                           (
                               [id] => 494
                               [name] => Personal Projects
                           )

                   )

           )
   ```

   i want like that if  i want fetch workspaces  name then i could fetch whole workspce
    data

Comment: i strongly suggest using a second table to hold the the data in associative array and referencing the primary table with a foreign key. if you use serialize, you can't query the data inside that column.

Comment: You need normalization, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: You could serialize/unserialize, but don't.

Comment: please improve my code so that i could understand your concepts.

Comment: i have to store id, name  both  how could i please modify code or send me snippet code.

Comment: Why do you want to store it that way ? If you really want to do so use mongoDB, it is non-relational DB, it stores data in a JSON format

Comment: please help to explain first answer of comment with code snippet